# Binding List in Thymeleaf; index out of bounds

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to bind a list in Thymeleaf and have followed tutorials and searched here; I have an issue in the indexes for the binding on submit are being jumped and then exceeded.  Firstly I'll detail the code, the core item is as follows:

```
package com.ziath.manu.stockcheck.model;

import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@Entity
public class StockItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    private String itemId;
    private String description;
    private Integer currentStockLevel;
    private Integer warnStockLevel;
    private Integer errorStockLevel;
    private Boolean purchaseOrderPlaced;

    public StockItem() {
        super();
       warnStockLevel = 0;
       errorStockLevel = 0;
    }

    public StockItem(String itemId, String description, Integer stockLevel) {

        this();
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.description = description;
        this.currentStockLevel = stockLevel;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String id) {
        this.itemId = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getCurrentStockLevel() {
        return currentStockLevel;
    }

    public void setCurrentStockLevel(Integer stockLevel) {
        this.currentStockLevel = stockLevel;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

    public Integer getWarnStockLevel() {
        return warnStockLevel;
    }

    public void setWarnStockLevel(Integer warnStockLevel) {
        this.warnStockLevel = warnStockLevel;
    }

    public Integer getErrorStockLevel() {
        return errorStockLevel;
    }

    public void setErrorStockLevel(Integer errorStockLevel) {
        this.errorStockLevel = errorStockLevel;
    }

    public Boolean getPurchaseOrderPlaced() {
        return purchaseOrderPlaced;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOrderPlaced(Boolean purchaseOrderPlaced) {
        this.purchaseOrderPlaced = purchaseOrderPlaced;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Then we have a wrapper so that the list can be bound:

```
package com.ziath.manu.stockcheck.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StockItems {

    private List<StockItem> stockItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<StockItem> getStockItems() {
        return stockItems;
    }

    public void setStockItems(List<StockItem> stockItems) {
        this.stockItems = stockItems;
    }


}
```

Then after this we have the thymeleaf template to bind the details to the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Stock Level from Manu</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" th:object="${formItems}" th:action="@{/saveStockLevelAlerts}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr th:each="stockItem, itemStat : *{stockItems}">

                <td th:text="${__${itemStat.index}__}" />
                <td th:text="${stockItem.itemId}" />
                <td th:text="${stockItem.description}" />
                <td th:text="${stockItem.currentStockLevel}" />
                <!-- if you want to know what this is go to https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list -->
                <input type="hidden" th:field="${formItems.stockItems[__${itemStat.index}__].id}" th:value="${stockItem.id}">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="${formItems.stockItems[__${itemStat.index}__].itemId}" th:value="${stockItem.itemId}">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="${formItems.stockItems[__${itemStat.index}__].description}" th:value="${stockItem.description}">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="${formItems.stockItems[__${itemStat.index}__].currentStockLevel}" th:value="${stockItem.currentStockLevel}">

                <td><input th:field="${formItems.stockItems[__${itemStat.index}__].warnStockLevel}" th:value="${stockItem.warnStockLevel}"></td>
                <td><input th:field="${formItems.stockItems[__${itemStat.index}__].errorStockLevel}" th:value="${stockItem.errorStockLevel}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Save">
        <input type="reset" id="resetButton" name="cancel" th:value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is displayed just fine and displays the items of which there are 305.  When I hit submit I get everything working just fine until I hit 256 items (note - 256 could be a clue but that would be a byte variable!).  Then I get an index out of bounds error as follows:

```
stock items size 256
com.ziath.manu.stockcheck.model.StockItem@50fa1f72[id=b9019869-0e10-4d24-bddd-173fb75f6570,itemId=Washer M3 Silver,description=Washer M3 Silver,currentStockLevel=26,warnStockLevel=0,errorStockLevel=0,purchaseOrderPlaced=<null>]
2019-02-01 12:54:55.509 ERROR 28408 --- [nio-8084-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'stockItems[256]' of bean class [com.ziath.manu.stockcheck.model.StockItems]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'stockItems[256]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256] with root cause
```

So it seems that I can read out 305 items with no issue but when I attempt to add them back in again I assume that Thymeleaf should be doing the following:

1. Make a new StockItem object
2. Get the List from the StockItems object
3. Add that StockItem to the end of the list
4. For each property get the StockItem at the end of the list and set the property

   This works fine until we get past 256 elements in the list.

   Does anyone have an example of handling a larger list and have any idea as to what is happening?

   Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution and it is nothing to do with Thymeleaf.  Spring sets a limit as to how many items you can bind to 255.  You need to change this if you want to go higher by adding:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(600);
}
```

Comment: Since the edit queue is full but doesn't seemed to be reviewed I wanted to add: You need to add the code to your Controller class.